# Connection QGIS 3.4.5 / PostgreSQL 9.3 with role group

Tags: qgis, postgresql, connection

I created 2 connection roles with PostgreSQL. Then, to manage more easily the privileges, I created a group role includind these roles (inherit).

I created a trigger which track data changes. I used the `session_user` function to know who made this action (Insert/ Update/ Delete) but it got me the group role login. I want to get the user (ie. role)  login and not the group role login.

I read that there is another function named `current_session` but it not get the user login.

Is there a another function I didn't find ?

Comment: This appears to be more of a PostgreSQL issue than a GIS one. The fact that you're using an ancient (and retired) PG release won't help.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to work with PostgreSQL 10 in 4 weeks... Maybe we should close the question ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`session_user` is the user that established the connection.  `current_user` is the explicitly set role

ex: connect as `myUser` -> `session_user` ==  `current_user` == `"myUser"`
`set role myRole;` -> `session_user`  == `"myUser"`; `current_user` == `"myRole"`

Both can be conveniently combined in a track-change trigger:

```
 IF session_user = current_user THEN
    NEW.UPDATE_USER := current_user;
 ELSE
    NEW.UPDATE_USER := session_user || '[' || current_user || ']';
 END IF;
```

Comment: To connect to Qgis, I had to add a PASSWORD to the _group role_, thereafter it changed the _group role_ in a _role connection_. So for PostgreSQL, the `session_user`is the new _role connection_ (ancient _group role_) and not the users behind. The `session_user` is the good function but doesn't see the users inside this new _role connection_ (ancient _group role_).

Comment: If I understand you properly, the 2 user roles are not used, and so can't be retrieved.

Comment: But the 2 users inherit from the _role connexion_. Why can't we trace it back to them ? The problem is the _role connection_ includes 2 other role connections (ie. the users). But, it seems that the connection from Qgis to PostreSQL needs a password, so it only connects to a role connection and not a group  role .